# Development environment Sinatra & MySQL in 2 computers

Tags: mysql, deployment, sinatra, installation

I'm developing a [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) and MySQL application. I'm using as development environment a Macbook Air and an iMac. The server runs on a FreeBSD VPS running unicorn behind nginx.

I'd like to somehow automate the whole procedure, I develop in both iMac and MBA. Depends on time I have free in the office (MBA) or time I spend writing code at home (iMac). I have setup MySQL on both macs.

I manually dump and restore the database in order to be able to test my application locally before making any change to the server.

I'd like to automate the process of: Syncing the MySQL database if possible, keep the code up-to-date to all locations without using cloud storage if possible.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many ways to solve this problem.
So this is just on idea how to achieve this.

Create a git repo on your server and write a small shell script which sync your db from somewhere. This script can you trigger by a git hook http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks

For your syncing script you may have a look at this -> https://github.com/xssnark/mysql-db-sync or I'm sure you find something.